# How to prevent event handlers from stacking on click events fired with the document selector on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm working on a project where I use AJAX to load different pieces of HTML code, in order to position the dynamic buttons inside each piece of HTML. I have to fire click events on the document `$(document).click();` because if I try to aim to them directly I get no answer from my Javascript due to the buttons being dynamic and they constantly change with each `load()`. So when jQuery binds the click event the first time and after, this button gets deleted and loaded again. JQuery doesn't seem to rebind the events using direct selectors.

The problem is that each time I fire the event click on the child selector it doesn't clear the click events bind from before. How do I clear those events to stop stacking the same events on different buttons with the same class or id

```
    $(document).on('click', '#saveBtn', function () {
        saveQuestion(id);
    });
```

Comment: You shouldn't reuse an `id` within a document--they are meant to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer:

```
$(document).off('click', '#saveBtn').on('click', '#saveBtn', function () {
    saveQuestion(id);
});
```

the key to understand this is that u unbind the events with off, but u should not call off with no arguments set, because it will kill the click functionality of the document so u pass the event and child selector to the off function to prevent a disaster, hope this helps for anyone who finds himself on this kind of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use unbind("click"). You can also name the event in case you only wish to unbind a single function binded to click. Let say you do two bindings and only wish to remove one, you can do this.

```
$(document).on('click.somename1', '#saveBtn', function (/*do something*/) {});
$(document).on('click.somename2', '#saveBtn', function (/*do something else*/) {});
$(document).unbind('click.somename1', '#saveBtn');
```

Comment: [`unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) is legacy. The preferred method as of jQuery 1.7 is [`off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/).